# Display table rows based on selected option from drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu

I'm need to display the table rows based on a selection of one drop down list. For example, If I've two select tags, in which I've options to select "type of business" & "state". If I select one type and if its sell, I'm displaying all the records which are having "sell" option and same for other option.

But my problem comes, when I change both options, I'm not able to get it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
// On changing the select option, display the rows which are relevant to the option selected.

$(document).on('change','.Cat_Table_Header', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).find("option:selected").text();       
    var selectedNoOfOption = parseInt($.inArray( id, optionsTextArray )) +1 ;
    $('#catleads tbody tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('td:eq('+selectedNoOfOption+')').text() == val) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    if(val == $(this).find("option:eq(0)").text()) {
        $('#catleads tbody tr').show();
    }
});
```

JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/776/

Comment: can you add jsfidlle   please ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/776/ This is the fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here another way to achieve your goal ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/779/)) which does not need an extra array of options.

It checks for every table row and every select if the select is set to allow all values or if the text from the select is equal to the text in the corresponding cell of that row.

```
$(document).on('change', '.Cat_Table_Header', function () {

    $('#catleads tbody tr').each(function (trIndex, tr) {
        var visible = true;
        $('.Cat_Table_Header').each(function (selectIndex, select) {
            var $option = $(select).find('option:selected');
            var $td = $(tr).find('td').eq(selectIndex);
            visible = visible && ($option.val() == 'all' || $td.text() == $option.text());
        });
        if (visible) {
            $(tr).show();
        } else {
            $(tr).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Raidri.. The fiddle works.. But, its not working in my case.. I don't understand why :(

Comment: Have your selects `value="all"` for the default option? Does the first select belong to the first column and so on? If that is all ok, can you show your case?

Comment: Yeah. I have put "all" option for the default option.  Here is the fiddle of my actual code. The select tag has the options values filled from the Ajax call by getting the data from the JSON file which is not included in the fiddle here.. http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/780/

Comment: Sure. I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey by the way, may I know why did you use $option & $td..? instead of using it as "var"

Comment: Good catch, you should add var in front of these. I use the `$` as sign that a variable is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 $(document).on('change','.Cat_Table_Header', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var val = $(this).find("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(",").split(",");
   var selectedNoOfOption = parseInt($.inArray( id, optionsTextArray )) +1 ;
   for (var item in val) {
     $('#catleads tbody tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).find('td:eq('+selectedNoOfOption+')').text() == item) {
           $(this).show();
        } else {
           $(this).hide();
        }
     });
   }; // end of for each

  if(val == $(this).find("option:eq(0)").text()) {
     $('#catleads tbody tr').show();
  }
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/jYHPE/36/

Note: The working demo on jsfiddle is just a prototype  of the actual problem indicated by OP, hence this is subjected to further improvement.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Thanks.. But its not working.. rather it says val.forEach is not a function.

Comment: @dreamweiver.. No.. Still not working.. Can you check the fiddle and try there?

Comment: sorry about that, there were couple of things missing in it, here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/jYHPE/36/ . this is a working prototype.